# Where is the root morpheme in Modern English evacuate and vacuum?

Tags: morphology, roots

They both are cognates (it can be easily proved by many etymological sources). The question is : Is it possible to consider VAC as a common root for evacuate and vacuum (we may go further - vacation, vacancy, vacuous etc.).

Comment: you should accept some of the answers to your questions (see http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I tried but I failed, They asked me to register but I failed... Maybe I missed smth. or my actions were not correct

Comment: should be trivial - if reading the faq does not help ask on chat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly they are related through Latin, from *e-* and *vacare* (*out of* and *to empty*) and from *vacuus* (*empty*), and in Latin the shared morpheme is *vac-*.

More interesting may be the relationships with [*vain*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vain), [*vast*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vast) and [*waste*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=waste) which have similar origins in Latin or proto-Indo-European, but which have more specific meanings in modern English.

Comment: Basically, all these words have roots in Latin, but no real root in English, am I right?

Comment: @Ham and Bacon: There are words like *evacuated* and *vacuumed* which might have been produced in English.  There are shortenings such as *evac* and *vac* which can mean much the same thing, and at some stage the shortenings may be expanded into something else.  Essentially the words came into English fully formed but productive.

Answer (score 2):

Going further back, these words all ultimately derive from the Proto-Indo-European root ***euə-** which has the english gloss *to lack, want; empty, vacant*.

So ultimately this includes many words including: vanish, want, vanity, wane, void, waste and even devastate.

Reference:
http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P0528.html

Comment: I think, if all these words were in PIE then we would think of them as of allomorphs of PIE*euə-. They all may be regarded as cognates now. And one would doubt the fact they they are all formed  from one common root (but each case must be analyzed of course).